# How to disable the automatic redirection in WordPress-htaccess-file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

WordPress has a function in its htaccess-file which performs an automatic redirection if the filenames match with an existing source.

For example if you type in http://rechnen-in-der-wolke.net/datensicherheit it will redirect you to http://rechnen-in-der-wolke.net/datensicherheit-cloud-anbieter-hagel-it/

**How do I disable this feature without diminishing the overall functionality?**

This is how the default htaccess-file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I already tried to remove  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` (nothing changes)  or `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` (nothing changes) or both of them (redirect loop).

Comment: It doesn't seem like a .htaccess cause - there is probably a redirect plugin in your WordPress

Comment: Agree with trojan, doesn't seem like a web server or core wordpress issue. What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
I have Akismet, Limit Login Attempts,WP Permalauts and Yoast SEO installed. Deactivated all of them and I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/301-redirect-instead-of-404-when-url-is-a-prefix-of-a-post-or-page-name

Following code has to be inserted in the functions.php:

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'no_redirect_on_404');
function no_redirect_on_404($redirect_url)
{
    if (is_404()) {
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Thanks to everyone helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does not redirect your URLs at will - but it stores every old URL along with its creating post, even if no longer used.

If you change a post slug, Wordpress redirects (301) the old to the new URL. This has nothing to do with .htaccess, it's a wordpress function. Unfortunately, I've never seen this feature properly documented in the codex. Hence I cannot tell you which wp_core function does this and where in the core it is located (and you do not want to touch the core, right?).

The previously used slug(s) are stored in the database in the `wp_postmeta` table. Check for `_wp_old_slug` in the meta_key column (the actual slugs being stored in the meta_value column). If you ever want this default behavior not to happen in a particular case, this is where to delete a value and search for "used" URLs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I come to believe that’s some kind of WordPress function, too. Maybe this one: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/ ? 

I had a look at the database and could find some '_wp_old_slug' entries but none for the specific post I mentioned above. Nevertheless you provided a solution for a problem I already encountered earlier during my WordPress usage - thanks for that! 

I’ll crosspost this question on the WordPress-Stackexchange. Let’s see if someone over there knows more.

Comment: Link: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71927/how-to-prevent-automatic-redirection

Comment: "WP redirects (301) from old to new URL" - This is completely wrong. If that happens on your site, you're using a plugin like Yoast Premium to make that happen. It is NOT default behaviour of WP.